# Filter Dataframe based on a list of codes, but each value of the column in question contains a list of many keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have data (df1) that looks like this:

```
INC_KEY        AISPREDOT
180008916795   "[110402.0, 110602.0, 140651.0, 140694.0, 150402.0, 161002.0]"
180008916796   "[140655.0, 140694.0]"
180008916797   "[853151.0]"
180008916798   "[110402.0, 140652.0, 150202.0]"
180008916799   "[857300.0]"
180008916800   "[650634.0]"
180008916801   "[710402.0, 772430.0, 854362.0, 854456.0, 877131.0]"
180008916802   "[816018.0, 854472.0]"
180008916803   "[442200.0, 442202.0, 450203.0]"
180008916804   "[853151.0]"
```

Where INC_KEY is set as the index. I also have a list of codes:

```
codes = [110402.0, 854362.0]
```

As you can see, each index contains a list of different codes (AISPREDOT), however the list is in the dataframe as a string. I need somehow read these strings as a list, and then filter df1 and create a new dataframe, df2, where df2 contains only the indices that contain **at least** one of the codes in the list *codes*.

So the resulting dataframe (df2) would look like this:

```
INC_KEY        AISPREDOT
180008916795   "[110402.0, 110602.0, 140651.0, 140694.0, 150402.0, 161002.0]"
180008916798   "[110402.0, 140652.0, 150202.0]"
180008916801   "[710402.0, 772430.0, 854362.0, 854456.0, 877131.0]"
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-astliteralevalnodeorstring-in-python) to turn the string into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a good use case for a regex and [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
codes = [110402.0, 854362.0]

pattern = fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(str, codes))})\b"
# '\\b(?:110402.0|854362.0\\b'

out = df.loc[df['AISPREDOT'].str.contains(pattern)]
```

Output:

```
        INC_KEY                                                       AISPREDOT
0  180008916795  "[110402.0, 110602.0, 140651.0, 140694.0, 150402.0, 161002.0]"
3  180008916798                                "[110402.0, 140652.0, 150202.0]"
6  180008916801            "[710402.0, 772430.0, 854362.0, 854456.0, 877131.0]"
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pfoVgI/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert strings as list then explode list and select right rows:

```
import ast

idx = (df['AISPREDOT'].str.strip('"').map(ast.literal_eval).explode()
                      .isin(codes).loc[lambda x: x].index)
out = df.loc[np.unique(idx)]
print(out)

# Output
                                                      AISPREDOT
INC_KEY                                                        
180008916795  "[110402.0, 110602.0, 140651.0, 140694.0, 1504...
180008916798                   "[110402.0, 140652.0, 150202.0]"
180008916799                                       "[857300.0]"
```

You can also make transformation persistent:

```
df['AISPREDOT'] = df['AISPREDOT'].str.strip('"').map(ast.literal_eval)
idx = df['AISPREDOT'].explode().isin(codes).loc[lambda x: x].index
out = df.loc[np.unique(idx)]
print(out)

# Output
                                                      AISPREDOT
INC_KEY                                                        
180008916795  [110402.0, 110602.0, 140651.0, 140694.0, 15040...
180008916798                     [110402.0, 140652.0, 150202.0]
180008916799                                         [857300.0]
```